# Does a Deadlock Occur in This Case?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

Am I right in saying that a deadlock is supposed to happen in the following case:

Object *P* calls a synch method of object *A*,
that calls a synch method of object *B*,
that calls a synch method of object *A*.

Sorry if it looks stupid of me, most probably it is. But that's *why* I'm asking. Thanks!

Comment: Why nobody said, that NetBeans could check for potential deadlock situations!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the information you give - no, a deadlock can't occur:

First, you don't mention multiple threads. A single thread can't cause a deadlock. But let's assume you have multiple threads.

So, if any other object, *from different thread* invokes some of these methods in reverse order, then a deadlock can occur.

The explanation of the situation is as follows: `Thread-1` obtains the lock required to enter `methodA`, and then tries to enter `methodB`. If at the same moment another thread - `Thread-2` invokes `methodB` and obtains the lock for it, then tries to enter `methodA`, but `Thread-1` already has the lock, so `Thread-2` waits. However, `Thread-1` can't enter `methodB` because `Thread-2` has the lock. And they wait forever (deadlock).

Answer (score 2):

No. It is same thread, synch methods are reenterable.

If you take definition from wikipedia: "A deadlock is a situation wherein **two or more** competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish". You have only one action (thread) .

Answer (score 2):

No, the thread will already hold the lock on A, so it won't deadlock. A thread can never contend for a lock with itself.

Comment: Actually, this is only true for re-entrant locks. In java, synchronized blocks do indeed use re-entrant locks, so you are OK.